# Call button click event on redirect page

Tags: asp.net

Calling a button click event on page load while redirecting this page from external project page is not working, I followed these steps.

1. Created a project and added a page and in that page one link button and
   its click event:

   ```
       string url = "http://localhost:5934/Login.aspx";
       string UserName = "XYZ";
       string UserID = "123";
       ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
       string data = string.Format("UserNameFromPMS={0}&UserIDFromPMS={1}", UserName, UserID);
       byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(data);
       HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
       httpRequest.Method = "POST";
       httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
       httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
       using (Stream stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
       {
           stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           stream.Close();
       }
       Response.Redirect("http://localhost:5934/Login.aspx");
   ```
2. On page load called that button's click event directly:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
           NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
           //string userName;
           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["UserNameFromPMS"]) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["UserIDFromPMS"]))
           {
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["UserNameFromPMS"]))
               {
                   userName = nvc["UserNameFromPMS"];
                   txtUsername.Text = nvc["UserNameFromPMS"].ToString();
               }
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nvc["UserIDFromPMS"]))
               {
                   txtPassword.Text = nvc["UserIDFromPMS"];
               }
           }
           btnLogin_OnClick(sender, e);
       }
   }
   ```
3. And tried to open modal popup on click event:

   ```
   protected void btnLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       mpeMessage.Show();
       return;
   }
   ```

But Modal pop not opened and also the `Text` property of text box controls was not set. What is the problem with my code ?

Comment: Looks like you got it all messed up. You probably want to **send request** to the page, not redirect the user to it.

Comment: Also, your if logic is a little weird. You're entering the first if when both values are not empty, yet you check 2 more times that they're not empty...

Comment: I want to send request and redirect to that page also and  on redirected page event directly call button click event also

Comment: Where is mpeMessage declared?

Comment: It is is Login.aspx as following

Comment: It is is Login.aspx as following   <ajx:ModalPopupExtender ID="modToCheck" runat="server" TargetControlID="hfToCheck"
                    PopupControlID="pnlToCheck">
                </ajx:ModalPopupExtender>